# GTK+ Documentation Typo? Undefined reference to gtk_combo_box_text_append

Tags: c, gtk

Can somebody verify whether the function [gtk_combo_box_text_append()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkComboBoxText.html#gtk-combo-box-text-append) is available from 2.24 or 3?  I was playing with it last night and I got undefined reference error to the specific function.

By the way, I did the test on Slackware64 13.37 on which I checked the version of gtk+2 is 2.24.4.

Comment: `prepend()` is also wrongly recorded as "Since 2.24". You should report it!

Comment: @Johannes Sasongko, thanks for your advice.  I've just emailed the documentation's maintainer.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/api-index-full.html#idxC) there is no such function in 2.24. There is function [gtk_combo_box_text_append_text](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkComboBoxText.html#gtk-combo-box-text-append-text) in both 2.24 and 3.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I haven't thought of checking out the 2.24's index.  This is very misleading... http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkComboBoxText.html#gtk-combo-box-text-append

Answer (score 2):

GTK+ 3.0 has:

```
void          gtk_combo_box_text_append_text     (GtkComboBoxText     *combo_box,
                                                  const gchar         *text);

void          gtk_combo_box_text_append          (GtkComboBoxText     *combo_box,
                                                  const gchar         *id,
                                                  const gchar         *text);
```

GTK+ 2.24 only has the former.